# Insert-update-delete web GUI

Tags: c#, html, web

I find myself creating Add/Edit/Delete/List GUI's so often that I'm sick and tired of it.
There must be some free package that solves this, right?

What I would like is something like this:

```
 {
    MyApplicationUser user = MyApplication.GetUserByID(1234);
    EditForm form = new EditForm("Title: Edit User"); //this is the magic object

    form.addFieldsFromObject(user);
 }


 function onFormSubmit(eventArgs e){
     MyApplicationUser user = form.GetSubmittedData();
     MyApplication.SaveUser(user);
 }
```

`AddFieldsFromObject` would automatically create a html form with fields mathing the datatype of the public properties of the object I feed it with.

Comment: Have a look at MvcScaffolding - http://mvcscaffolding.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of frameworks that try to solve this problem. [ASP.NET Dynamic Data](http://www.asp.net/dynamicdata) may be a good place to start. It uses a template-based system to provide basic CRUD (Create, Retrieve, Update, Delete) user interfaces with very minimal custom code.

ASP.NET MVC also does a pretty good job with its editor models:

```
// View code
@using(Html.BeginForm(...)) {
    @Html.EditorForModel()
}

// Action code
public ActionResult ShowForm(int userId)
{
    var model = // get model from user ID;
    return View(model);
}


public ActionResult SaveForm(Model model)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Save model
    }
}
```

[LightSwitch](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/lightswitch) tries to solve this same problem by auto-generating basic scaffolding code for you to produce an experience similar to Microsoft Access. But since it's using actual C# code, you can alter the code to provide more functionality if you find that your needs have grown beyond the original scope of the project.